# GridView exibe área em branco no rodapé no Lenovo Vibe K5 (API Level 22)

Tags: android, android-layout

Eu tenho um GridView que exibe 4 imagens que devem preencher a tela mas isso não acontece. Eu não adicionei nenhum padding ou margin no layout e ja tentei usar os atributos fillViewPort e fitsSystemWindow. Eu acho que o problema esta relacionado aos botões físicos do aparelho que não são virtuais no Lenovo K5 e talvez afete o layout, mas não sei como resolver.

Aqui está o problema: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como se pode ver existe um espaço em branco no rodapé e é ele que quero remover.

Aqui está o codigo:

activity_main.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
class="guilherme.udacity.popularmovies.MainFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridview_movies"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:verticalSpacing="0dp" />
```

Comment: Não é motivo pra negativo, e sim pra fechamento, apenas lembrando...

Comment: Vlw não sabia, achei que talvez fosse integrado as plataformas ingles e portugues